# ViewModel and user interface project locations

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, mvvm

Im writing a wpf project and using the MVVM paradigm, what i was wondering is if i should write my view model classes in their own project.

Advantages i can see is that your ui project would never have to know about your business logic. (not have a reference to it)

however if i want to use the ICommand interface in my view model i still need a reference to PresentationCore which may indicate that i should be in my ui project.

comments suggestions most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an overwhelmingly compelling way to do it one way or the other. I tend to keep VMs and their views in the same assembly, but within a different folder structure. For example, I might have *ViewModels/Foo/Bar/CustomerViewModel* and *Views/Foo/Bar/CustomerView.xaml*.

I don't think there's a problem splitting out the views and view models either. Having the VM assembly reference view-related assemblies such as PresentationCore is only natural. After all, your view models are part of your view layer.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you reference PresentationCore in your ViewModel (which is currently unavoidable if you want to use ICommand) you are leaking all manner of undesirable View-related features into your ViewModel. For example, MessageBox.Show, when you see this called in a unit test it drives home why it's bad.

To answer the question, yes keep your View and ViewModel in separate projects. I wondered this myself but after going down the separate projects route it took me awhile to appreciate but it has been really valuable in making me stick to a clean MVVM solution, and the lessons from this have greatly improved my overall solution architecture. It's all about reducing dependencies on unnecessary assemblies using interfaces and if necessary the Adapter pattern. One example is that my View project, being an entrypoint has a reference to Ninject, but I don't want my ViewModel to have that reference. Otherwise someone might come along and use the Ninject static Kernel directly.

Regarding ICommand, I don't know the history having only used WPF since 4, but it feels like MVVM was an afterthought. I'm not sure why else Microsoft would have put this interface in PresentationCore. I'm hoping this will be addressed in a future release with a separate assembly for the ViewModel layer.

Comment: This just boils down to discipline though. What's to prevent an undisciplined developer adding a reference to PresentationFramework from your VM assembly? Discipline is required regardless of whether you have separated your VMs out into another assembly or not.